# Show updated data that has been retrieved from http call Angular

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, http, angular-lifecycle-hooks

I am pushing data from a data response that contains a nested array into an array of static data in my component.

Programmatically the data is being pushed into the object properly. I saw this while walking through the method and saw my for loop is successfully adding the items to the already existing array. This is being added 'OnInit"

It is simply not adding the items to the table in my view.

```
 ngOnInit(): void {
    this._data.getContacts().subscribe(data => this.addAsyncData(data));
  }

  addAsyncData(result){
    for(let i =0; i < result.length; i++) {
      this.people.push(result[i]);
  }
}
```

I suspect this has something to do with lifecycle hooks..

Comment: It's because the `ngOnInit` lifecycle hook is only called when the component is being initialised: https://angular.io/api/core/OnInit

Comment: Yeah I suspect that. Not sure how to use OnChanges in this situation.

Comment: Try to create a stackblitz showcasing the problem (you can use rxjs.of() to simulate observables).

Answer (score 2):

I'd need to see more code to be sure, but it seems likely that your changes are not being reflected in the rendering of your template because your additions to your 'people' array are not triggering change detection.

This is because the change detector looks for changes to the references of your bound objects (in this case, the 'pointer' to the array). To trigger change detection you need to change the reference (i.e. create a new array).

Try this:

```
addAsyncData(result){
    this.people = [...this.people, ...result];
}
```

It creates a new array, with the original content and the new content.

Comment: Unclear exactly how my for loop and such can go in the values of an array can you please clarify?

Comment: Your data is already in any array -the one that you are looping over. You don't need to loop over the array the code above creates a new array containing your old 'people' array and the new data.

Comment: This is a very interesting solution and worked perfectly.